# Change PHP Tag Syntax Highlighting

Tags: php, html, wordpress, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I'm working with WordPress which mixes PHP and HTML in their `.php` files. Right now open/closing PHP and HTML tags are the same blue color ( on the dark theme ). I'm wondering if there's a way to change the color of the opening/closing PHP tags to better differentiate the PHP and HTML sections? Here's a screenshot demonstrating what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried other colour themes?

Comment: @MarkSeah I've tried the light themes and they're all highlighted the same.

Comment: Sorry, but had to down-vote because this has nothing to do with Wordpress, HTML or PHP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `material-theme` as an extension. Change `color theme` and `set accent color`  as your wish. You will find those settings on `preference`. On Linux press `ctrl+shift+p` and search for color theme after installing the Material theme or any other theme that you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Add that to your settings.json (It will set the color to #d65656)

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": [
          "punctuation.section.embedded.begin.php",
          "punctuation.section.embedded.end.php",
        ],
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#d65656"
        },
      }
    ]
  }
```